# If $\theta(h)$ is such that $f(3+h)-f(3) = hf'(3+\theta(h)h)$, what is $\lim_{h \to 0} θ(h)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, mean-value-theorem

> **Problem.** Let $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$, and $\theta(h)$ be a function such that
> $$f(3+h)-f(3) = hf'(3+\theta(h)h)$$
> for all $h \in (−1, 1)$. Then $\lim_{h \to 0} θ(h)$ is equal to?
> (rounded off to two decimal places).

This question is from IIT JAM exam.

**First Approach :** I tried it to equate with the expression of Taylor's series for $f$ at $x=3$ but cannot conclude anything .
**Second Approach:** Lagrange's Mean Value theorem , rearranged this expression in the form of $f'$ then evaluated derivative of $f$ at $3$ but there is no term containing $h$ & that is different from the actual answer. Both these approaches are almost same & I cannot proceed further evaluating limit. Any suggestion how to proceed ?

Comment: "my results come out to be $0$" Could you edit your question to show how? By Taylor the LHS is $hf'(3)+\frac12h^2f''(3)+o(h^2\theta^2)$, while the RHS is $hf'(3)+h^2\theta f''(3)+o(h^2)$, so $\theta\sim\frac12$. But I recommend you try the strategy in @Taladris's comment below.

Comment: Since you have a formula, you can solve the equation and find $\theta(h)$ explicitly, then compute the limit

Comment: @J.G. I was just messing up the equation I took the expansion till first derivative only , thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, please read my answer about the generalization of the problem and tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Problem.** Let $\,f(x)=3\sqrt x\,$ for $\,x\in(0,\infty)\,$ and $\,\theta(h)$ be a function such that
> $$f(3+h)-f(3)=hf'\big(3+\theta(h)h\big)$$
> for all $\,h\in(−1,1)\,.\;$ Then $\,\lim\limits_{h\to0}\theta(h)\,$ is equal to ?
> (rounded off to two decimal places).

**Solution:**

Since $\;f(x)=3\sqrt x\;$ for any $\;x\in(0,+\infty)\;$ and
$f(3+h)-f(3)=hf'\big(3+\theta(h)h\big)\;$ for all $\,h\in(−1, 1)\;,$
it follows that

$3\sqrt{3+h}-3\sqrt3=\dfrac{3h}{2\sqrt{3+\theta(h)h}}\;\;$ for all $\;h\in(-1,1)\;\;,$

$3\left(\sqrt{3+h}-\sqrt3\right)\left(\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3\right)=\dfrac{3h\left(\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3\right)}{2\sqrt{3+\theta(h)h}}\;\;,$

$3h=\dfrac{3h\left(\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3\right)}{2\sqrt{3+\theta(h)h}}\;\;$ for all $\;h\in(-1,1)\;\;,$

$\sqrt{3+\theta(h)h}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3}2\;\;$ for all $\;h\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}\;\;,$

$\theta(h)h=\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3}2\right)^{\!2}\!-3\;\;$ for all $\;h\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}\;\;,$

$\theta(h)h=\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3}2+\sqrt3\!\right)\!\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3}2-\sqrt3\!\right)\;\;,$

$\theta(h)h=\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+3\sqrt3}2\!\right)\!\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}-\sqrt3}2\!\right)\;\;,$

$\theta(h)=\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+3\sqrt3}2\!\right)\!\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}-\sqrt3}{2h}\!\right)\;\;,$

$\theta(h)=\left(\!\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+3\sqrt3}2\!\right)\!\left[\dfrac1{2\left(\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3\right)}\right]\;\;,$

$\theta(h)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+h}+3\sqrt3}{4\left(\sqrt{3+h}+\sqrt3\right)}\;\;$ for all $\;h\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}\;.$

Consequently,

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\theta(h)=\dfrac{4\sqrt3}{8\sqrt3}=\dfrac12\;.$

---

We can generalize the problem, but it is not necessary that the function $\,f\,$ is twice continuously differentiable. It is sufficient that it is twice differentiable just at one point.

**Generalization of the problem:**

> Let $\,a,b,c,r\in\Bbb R\,$ such that $\,a<b\,,\,r>0\,$ and $\,(c-r,c+r)\subseteq(a,b)\,.\,$ Let $\,f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R\,$ be a differentiable function on $\,(c-r,c+r)\,.$
> If there exists $\,f’’(c)\neq0\,$ and if $\,\theta:(-r,r)\to(0,1)\,$ is a function such that
> $$f(c+h)-f(c)=hf'\big(c+\theta(h)h\big)$$
> for all $\,h\in(−r,r)\,.\;$ Then $\,\lim\limits_{h\to0}\theta(h)\,$ is equal to ?
> (rounded off to two decimal places).

**Solution:**

For any $\,h\in(-r,r)\setminus\{0\}\,,\,$ it results that

$h\big[f'\big(c+\theta(h)h\big)-f’(c)\big]=f(c+h)-f(c)-hf’(c)\;\;,$

$\theta(h)\!\left[\dfrac{f'\!\big(c\!+\!\theta(h)h\big)\!-\!f’(c)}{\theta(h)h}\right]=\dfrac{f(c\!+\!h)\!-\!f(c)\!-\!hf’(c)}{h^2}\;\;.$

By applying L'Hôpital's rule and by using the definition of second derivative at a point, we get that

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(c\!+\!h)\!-\!f(c)\!-\!hf’\!(c)}{h^2}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f’\!(c\!+\!h)\!-\!f’\!(c)}{2h}=\dfrac{f’’\!(c)}2\,.$

Moreover, by definition of second derivative, we get that

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f'\big(c+\theta(h)h\big)-f’(c)}{\theta(h)h}=f’’(c)\;.$

Since $\,f’’(c)\neq0\,,\,$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\theta(h)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)-hf’(c)}{h^2}}{\frac{f'\big(c+\theta(h)h\big)-f’(c)}{\theta(h)h}}=\dfrac{\frac{f’’(c)}2}{f’’(c)}=\dfrac12\;.$

Comment: I have one doubt, In the step you have applied L'Hôpital's, where did the term $-hf'(c)$ go?

Comment: @DeepakKumar, when you apply L'Hôpital's rule, you have to differentiate both numerator and denominator and the derivative of $\color{brown}{-hf’(c)}$ is $\color{brown}{-f’(c)}$ indeed you are differentiating with respect to $\color{brown}{h}\,.$ Notice that the derivative of $\color{brown}{f(c)}$ is $\color{brown}{0}\,$ because it is a constant with respect to $\color{brown}{h}\,.$

Comment: It means that $limit$ of $\theta(h)$ is independent of the function choosen provided $f$ should be twice differentiable at $c$ & $f"(c)≠0$ .Thanks bro, have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

We consider a slight generalization of the problem, since this clarifies the structure of the problem without introducing too much abstraction.

Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable on an interval $(a-r, a+r)$ with $f''(a) \neq 0$, and let $\theta(h)$ be defined for $|h| < r$ by the relation

$$ f(a+h) - f(a) = h f'(a + \theta(h)h). $$

By Taylor's approximation, there exists $\xi_0 = \xi_0(h)$ and $\xi_1 = \xi_1(h)$ such that $|\xi_i(h)| \leq |h|$ and the following equalities hold:

$$ f(a + h) = f(a) + f'(a)h + f''(a+\xi_0(h))\frac{h^2}{2!}, $$

$$ f'(a + h) = f'(a) + f''(a + \xi_1(h))h. $$

Plugging this to the defining equation of $\theta(h)$, it follows that

$$ f'(a)h + f''(a+\xi_0(h))\frac{h^2}{2!}
= h \left[ f'(a) + f''(a + \xi_1(\theta(h) h)) \theta(h) h \right]. $$

Rearranging this for $\theta(h)$ and taking limit as $h \to 0$,

$$ \theta(h) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{f''(a+\xi_0(h))}{f''(a + \xi_1(\theta(h) h))} \to \frac{1}{2} \frac{f''(a)}{f''(a)} = \frac{1}{2} $$

since $\xi_i(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ and $f''$ is continuous at $a$ with non-zero value.

Comment: Is the claim actually false if $f''=0$? At least for $f(x)=x^2$ we still have $\theta=\frac12$ (identically).

Comment: @Milten, Indeed it can be false. If $f(x)=x^3$ and $a=0$, then $\theta(h)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. However, I am not sure if the claim remains true if $f$ is a $C^3$-function such that $f''(a)=0$ but $f'''(a)=0$. Playing with a cubic case seems to suggest that this is probably true, but let me leave it to others.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I should have checked the next example before commenting  I thought there might have some kind of continuity argument possible...

Comment: Oops, I made a type in the previous comment. What I wanted to say in the second part was: "However, I am not sure if the claim remains true if $f$ is a $C^3$-function such that $f''(a)=0$ but $\color{red}{f'''(a)\neq0}$."